# Python Bubble sort

Tags: python, sorting, bubble-sort

Hey so the code works perfectly thank you very much!

i just have one more question.
I want to have an arrow displayed in between the two coulmns. i created this code but i dont really know how to make it go in between the columns that are being switched. any suggestions?

```
def arrow(lst, i):                 # function for the arrow
if (lst[i], lst[i+1] == lst[i+1], lst[i]):
    t.home()
    t.penup()
                     # im thinking something goes here but i dont know what :P
    t.pendown()
    t.pencolor("red")
    t.right(90)
    t.forward(20)
```

any help would be very appreciated! Thank you!
btw the rest of the code is like imran's code! :) thank yoU!

Comment: Not pertinent to your problem, but your `swapped` variable has the wrong sense (you set it to false when you swap). Should think about reversing all use.

Comment: Your definition of "swapped" seems to differ from the norm.

Comment: And you function name is not good.

Comment: What is `n` in this line: `for i in range(n)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your code looks a lot like one of the versions of bubble sort [here](http://www.codecodex.com/wiki/Bubble_sort#Python). The main issue why your version isn't working is because you are comparing lst at index i with i-1 which fails when i=0. Change that section to:

```
        if (lst[i] < lst[i + 1]):
            swapped = False
            lst[i+1], lst[i] = lst[i], lst[i+1]
```

Also, don't define n outside of the function (which should ideally be called bubble_sort, or something similar), that is bad programming, a bug waiting to happen. I don't know what you are trying to accomplish with `lst = [lst]`. Might want to use a different variable name.

**Edit:** 
I made some liberal changes to your code. I put all the drawing call inside the bubble sort. The bubble sort also internally converts the list into a list of tuples where the second element of the tuple is the color. The for loop at the end of your code doesn't do anything worthwhile. I think your main issue was that it was not pausing between each iteration of the while loop so you don't get to see the elements of the list bubble up.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import turtle as t

def draw(lst, width):
  for x in lst:
    height = x[0]
    t.color(x[1])
    t.forward(width)
    t.left(90)
    t.forward(height)
    t.left(90)
    t.forward(width)
    t.left(90)
    t.forward(height)
    t.left(90)
    t.penup()
    t.forward(30)
    t.pendown()

def bubble_sort(orig_lst):  
  lst = [ (x, "blue") for x in orig_lst ]
  n = len(lst)-1 
  t.pensize(3)
  draw(lst, width)
  swapped = True  
  while swapped:  
    swapped = False  
    for i in range(n):  
        if lst[i+1][0] < lst[i][0]:  
            lst[i], lst[i+1] = lst[i+1], lst[i]
            lst[i] = (lst[i][0], "green")  
            swapped = True 
            next = raw_input("hit any key to continue ")
            t.home()
            t.clear() 
            draw(lst,width)
  newLst = [ x[0] for x in lst ]
  return newLst

# TOP LEVEL
original_lst = input("Enter list to be sorted: ")
width = input("Provide the width: ")

newLst = bubble_sort(original_lst)
print "Done! Sorted list is: ", newLst
next = raw_input("hit any key to exit ")
```

Comment: could any1 help me please?

Comment: one more question, do you know how to create an arrow under the list index that is being swapped each time? like it should indicate which one is being swapped :)

Comment: @SunShine I don't think you should update the original question like this. To the casual observer the answers other people have posted do not make sense given the new question. You should upvote, choose an answer and close the question. You should then create a new question with the new problem you are encountering with a minimal example of what you are trying to do and have tried.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a bubble sort based on your code:

```
import types

def bubble_sort(lst):
    assert(type(lst)==types.ListType)
    for index in range(1,len(lst)):
        while index > 0 and lst[index-1] > lst[index]:
            lst[index-1] , lst[index] = lst[index] , lst[index-1]
            index -= 1
    return

lst = input("Enter list to be sorted: ")
print "Original: ",lst
bubble_sort(lst)
print "Sorted: ",lst
```

The test looks like:

```
C:\Users\NAME\Desktop>bubble.py
Enter list to be sorted: [4, 24, 25, 2, 6, -1, 73, 1]
Original:  [4, 24, 25, 2, 6, -1, 73, 1]
Sorted:  [-1, 1, 2, 4, 6, 24, 25, 73]
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

There are just a few things to edit from your original code, it is better to have two for loops for this to check the values for this. Also before you had `[i-1]` which defeats the purpose of a bubble sort as you are sorting from left to right if that makes sense. Anyways here is what I have done.

```
def swap(lst):
    for i in range (len(lst)):
        for j in range (len(lst)-1):
            if lst[j] > lst[j+1]:
                lst[j], lst[j+1] = lst[j+1], lst[j]
                print (lst)


lst = input("Enter list to be sorted: ")
print (lst)
swap(lst)
```